# iOS-like squircle shape in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to replicate the `Post` button of the Threads iOS app in Flutter. It has a smooth corner which I found out to be called a squircle.

[image: Threads button]

So far I've come to this solution which gives me a kind of smooth corner but doesn't exactly replicate the shape of the image above:

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: const ShapeBorderClipper(
    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(40),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: CupertinoButton(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 20,
      vertical: 15,
    ),
    color: Colors.black,
    child: const Text(
      'Post',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

[image: Flutter button]

Is this achievable in Flutter or is it something particular to iOS native apps?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the solution presented in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/e35e8d5877371417e9803143e2501b0a) which is represented below with a red border on top of the image of the shape I'm trying to replicate. It gets close, but not exactly the same shape yet.

[image]

Comment: check this: https://flutterappworld.com/a-flutter-study-and-comparision-of-different-squircle-shapeborder/

Comment: Thanks @pskink that definitely answers my question

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

I refrenced this gist [here](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/e35e8d5877371417e9803143e2501b0a)

```
  class SquircleBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final BorderSide side;
  final double superRadius;

  const SquircleBorder({
    this.side =  BorderSide.none,
    this.superRadius = 5.0,
  })
    : assert(side != null),
      assert(superRadius != null);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(side.width);

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return new SquircleBorder(
      side: side.scale(t),
      superRadius: superRadius * t,
    );
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return _squirclePath(rect.deflate(side.width), superRadius);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return _squirclePath(rect, superRadius);
  }

  static Path _squirclePath(Rect rect, double superRadius) {
    final c = rect.center;
    final dx = c.dx * (1.0 / superRadius);
    final dy = c.dy * (1.0 / superRadius);
    return new Path()
      ..moveTo(c.dx, 0.0)
      ..relativeCubicTo(c.dx - dx, 0.0, c.dx, dy, c.dx, c.dy)
      ..relativeCubicTo(0.0, c.dy - dy, -dx, c.dy, -c.dx, c.dy)
      ..relativeCubicTo(-(c.dx - dx), 0.0, -c.dx, -dy, -c.dx, -c.dy)
      ..relativeCubicTo(0.0, -(c.dy - dy), dx, -c.dy, c.dx, -c.dy)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    switch (side.style) {
      case BorderStyle.none:
        break;
      case BorderStyle.solid:
        var path = getOuterPath(rect.deflate(side.width / 2.0), textDirection: textDirection);
        canvas.drawPath(path, side.toPaint());
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Container(
        width: 100.0,//customize to your desire height
        height: 56.0,//customize to your desired width
        child: new Material(
          color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
          shape: new SquircleBorder(
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey[800]!, width: 3.0),
          ),
          child: Center(
          child: Text('Post'))
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited my question with the result of this solution. It gets close, but it's not exactly the same shape I'm trying to replicate yet.